# CASE IN statement with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to make a CASE statement with an IN clause?

```
SELECT
CASE c.Number
IN ('1121231','31242323') THEN 1
IN ('234523','2342423') THEN 2
END AS Test
FROM tblClient c
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Yes. You need to use the "Searched" form rather than the "Simple" form of the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN c.Number IN ( '1121231', '31242323' ) THEN 1
         WHEN c.Number IN ( '234523', '2342423' ) THEN 2
       END AS Test
FROM   tblClient c
```

Answer (score 14):

You can return the same value from several matches:

```
SELECT
  CASE c.Number
    WHEN '1121231' THEN 1
    WHEN '31242323' THEN 1
    WHEN '234523' THEN 2
    WHEN '2342423' THEN 2
  END AS Test
FROM tblClient c
```

This will probably result in the same execution plan as Martins suggestion, so it's more a matter of how you want to write it.

Comment: problem is that you are not using the 'in' statement so you are not really answering the question

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: If you only want to answer the question exactly as stated, the only possible answer is "No", and that's not very constructive.

Comment: How is the answer "No"? I write `CASE` statements with `IN` all the time... as does Martin Smith, so it seems.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: You can't have an `IN` clause in a `CASE` statement, which is exactly what the question was. What you have is an expression with `IN` which is used in a condition in a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @Guffa, the downvote is probably either because you said you can't have an `IN` clause in a `CASE` statement, which doesn't seem to hold true for SQL Server 2008 R2 and higher (not sure about 2005, though), or because your answer has more duplication than Martin Smith's answer.

Comment: @Sam: Perhaps, but neither is a valid reason.

Answer (score 3):

The question is specific to SQL Server, but I would like to extend [Martin Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449523/5070879).

SQL:2003 standard allows to define multiple values for **simple case expression**:

```
SELECT CASE c.Number
          WHEN '1121231','31242323' THEN 1
          WHEN '234523','2342423' THEN 2
       END AS Test
FROM tblClient c;
```

It is optional feature: [Comma-separated predicates in simple CASE expression“ (F263)](https://modern-sql.com/feature/case#comma-separated-form).

Syntax:

```
CASE <common operand>
     WHEN <expression>[, <expression> ...] THEN <result>
    [WHEN <expression>[, <expression> ...] THEN <result>
     ...]
    [ELSE <result>]
END
```

As for know I am not aware of any RDBMS that actually supports that syntax.

Comment: Just tried this in Sql 2012, and if it did work at one time, it doesn't seem to anymore. Which is sad. Is a much clearer syntax. Oh well... Martin Smith's seems to work okay.

Comment: @eidylon I stated that this syntax is part of SQL Standard. It is optional and personally I don't know any RDBMS that implements it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have more numbers or if you intend to add new test numbers for `CASE` then you can use a more flexible approach:

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE
(
    Number VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Class TINYINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT @Numbers
VALUES ('1121231',1);
INSERT @Numbers
VALUES ('31242323',1);
INSERT @Numbers
VALUES ('234523',2);
INSERT @Numbers
VALUES ('2342423',2);

SELECT c.*, n.Class
FROM   tblClient c  
LEFT OUTER JOIN   @Numbers n ON c.Number = n.Number;
```

Also, instead of table variable you can use a regular table.