# SQL Case with multiple values

Tags: sql

Is there a condensed form of the following statement?

```
SELECT Name, Case StatusID WHEN 1 THEN 'Alive' WHEN 2 THEN 'Alive' WHEN 3 THEN 'Alive' WHEN 4 THEN 'Dying' ELSE 'Dead' END FROM People
```

for example

```
CASE StatusID WHEN 1,2,3 THEN 'Alive'
```

or

```
CASE StatusID WHEN 1 OR 2 OR 3 THEN 'Alive'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CASE IN statement with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449509/case-in-statement-with-multiple-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle, assuming statuid is never <= 0:

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN statusid < 4 THEN 'Alive'
                  WHEN statusid = 4 THEN 'Dying'
                  ELSE 'Dead' END AS some_alias
  FROM people
```

You can also use DECODE.

Comment: You can't use inequalities, but  you can do DECODE(1, 'Alive', 2, 'Alive', 3, 'Alive', 4, 'Dying', 'Dead'). In fact, that may actually be more compact.

Comment: Sorry... didn't specify the DBMS. It's MSSQL 2008 R2, so no DECODE.

Answer (score 8):

depending on the DB you use the following will do the trick

```
SELECT 
Name, 
Case WHEN StatusID  IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) THEN 'Alive' WHEN StatusID = 4 THEN 'Dying' ELSE 'Dead' END 
FROM People
```