# Combine results from 2 SQL Server queries into 2 columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I currently have 2 SQL queries:

```
select 
    SUM(CASE T1.DOCTYPE 
          WHEN '1' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *1
          WHEN '4' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
          WHEN '5' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
          WHEN '6' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
       END) as [Payables TB]
from PM20000 T1

select
    sum(PERDBLNC) as [GL Balance]
from GL10110
where ACTINDX = '130'
```

which return 2 results like this:

```
Payables TB
1520512.30

GL Balance
-1520512.30
```

I would like to combine the results into 2 columns and have a variance column like below -

```
Payables TB      GL Balance       Variance
1520512.30       -1520512.30      0.00
```

Thank you

Comment: perhaps some sort of attempt is in order?

Comment: Do you have some code that illustrates whether or not you have tried something?

Comment: perhaps don't assume that a forum post is my first point of call instead of my last resort? I am very familiar with joins but the tables are not related and I have never come across this situation before where my query can't be created with a join. I spent a long time searching forums but as being new to programming and completely self taught I didn't even know the correct terminology for what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap these into CTE's to reuse the values to compute the difference. With no join condition you will just need to `CROSS JOIN`, as long as these return just one row each :

```
WITH Payables AS
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(
      CASE  
        WHEN T1.DOCTYPE IN ('1') THEN T1.CURTRXAM *1
        WHEN T1.DOCTYPE IN ('4','5','6') THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
        -- ? ELSE
      END) as [Payables TB]
  FR PM20000 T1
),
Balance AS
(
  SELECT
  SUM(PERDBLNC) as [GL Balance]
  FROM GL10110
  WHERE ACTINDX = '130'
)
SELECT 
  Payables.[Payables TB], 
  Balance.[GL Balance],  
  Payables.[Payables TB] + Balance.[GL Balance] AS Variance
  FROM 
    Payables, Balance; -- OR Payables CROSS JOIN Balance
```

Since you seem to be doing the same projection for `T1.DOCTYPE` 4, 5 and 6 in the first query, you can replace it with a [`CASE WHEN x IN (...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7449523/314291)

Comment: Great thankyou StuartLC I am very familiary with joins but wasn't aware of how to use cross joins when the tables are not related, I will read up on these. Thanks for pointing out the duplication in my CASE I will simplify it using IN.

Comment: Out of interest, you surely don't want to hard code the variance like in the accepted answer? The reason I used CTEs (or you could use derived tables) is so that you can re-use the aggregate SUM columns without repeating the query from scratch?

Comment: No I definitely don't want the variance hard coded. I am unable to up vote but it says I accepted your answer?

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
select
    (select 
        SUM(CASE T1.DOCTYPE 
        WHEN '1' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *1
        WHEN '4' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
        WHEN '5' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
        WHEN '6' THEN T1.CURTRXAM *-1
        END) as [Payables TB]
        from PM20000 T1) as Payables TB,

    (select
        sum(PERDBLNC) as [GL Balance]
        from GL10110
        where ACTINDX = '130') as GL Balance,

    0.00 as Variance
```