# Case in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have an SQL statement that has a `CASE` from `SELECT` and I just can't get it right. Can you guys show me an example of `CASE` where the cases are the conditions and the results are from the cases. For example:

```
     Select xxx, yyy
     case : desc case when bbb then 'blackberry';
     when sss then 'samsung';
     end 
     from (select ???? .....
```

where the results show

```
 name                         age       handphone
xxx1                         yyy1      blackberry
xxx2                         yyy2      blackberry
```

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38874485/1045444) explaining two case types 1. Simple CASE expression 2. Searched CASE expressions. And both type's case usage in SELECT, UPDATE, With ORDER BY, With HAVING queries.

Answer (score 221):

The MSDN is a good reference for these type of questions regarding syntax and usage.  This is from the Transact SQL Reference - CASE page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" = 
  CASE 
     WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
     WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
     ELSE 'Over $1000'
  END
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
GO
```

Another good site you may want to check out if you're using SQL Server is [SQL Server Central](http://sqlservercentral.com).  This has a large variety of resources available for whatever area of SQL Server you would like to learn.

Comment: Since each `case` condition is checked in the order specified and the first `true` condition wins there is no need to perform duplicate checks, e.g. `WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN` can be written `WHEN ListPrice < 250 THEN` since the prior line has established that `ListPrice` is not `< 50`. (Just like you handled `< 50` without checking for `0` again.) Aside: Negative list prices will drop into the `'Under $50'` bucket.

Answer (score 102):

I think these could be helpful for you .

**Using a `SELECT` statement with a simple `CASE` expression**

Within a `SELECT` statement, a simple `CASE` expression allows for only an equality check; no other comparisons are made. The following example uses the `CASE` expression to change the display of product line categories to make them more understandable.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
GO
```

**Using a `SELECT` statement with a searched `CASE` expression**

Within a `SELECT` statement, the searched `CASE` expression allows for values to be replaced in the result set based on comparison values. The following example displays the list price as a text comment based on the price range for a product.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" = 
      CASE 
         WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
         WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
         WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
         ELSE 'Over $1000'
      END
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
GO
```

**Using `CASE` in an `ORDER BY` clause**

The following examples uses the `CASE` expression in an `ORDER BY` clause to determine the sort order of the rows based on a given column value. In the first example, the value in the SalariedFlag column of the HumanResources.Employee table is evaluated. Employees that have the SalariedFlag set to 1 are returned in order by the BusinessEntityID in descending order. Employees that have the SalariedFlag set to 0 are returned in order by the BusinessEntityID in ascending order. In the second example, the result set is ordered by the column TerritoryName when the column CountryRegionName is equal to 'United States' and by CountryRegionName for all other rows.

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, SalariedFlag
FROM HumanResources.Employee
ORDER BY CASE SalariedFlag WHEN 1 THEN BusinessEntityID END DESC
        ,CASE WHEN SalariedFlag = 0 THEN BusinessEntityID END;
GO


SELECT BusinessEntityID, LastName, TerritoryName, CountryRegionName
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CASE CountryRegionName WHEN 'United States' THEN TerritoryName
         ELSE CountryRegionName END;
```

**Using `CASE` in an `UPDATE` statement**

The following example uses the `CASE` expression in an `UPDATE` statement to determine the value that is set for the column VacationHours for employees with SalariedFlag set to 0. When subtracting 10 hours from VacationHours results in a negative value, VacationHours is increased by 40 hours; otherwise, VacationHours is increased by 20 hours. The `OUTPUT` clause is used to display the before and after vacation values.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = 
    ( CASE
         WHEN ((VacationHours - 10.00) < 0) THEN VacationHours + 40
         ELSE (VacationHours + 20.00)
       END
    )
OUTPUT Deleted.BusinessEntityID, Deleted.VacationHours AS BeforeValue, 
       Inserted.VacationHours AS AfterValue
WHERE SalariedFlag = 0;
```

**Using `CASE` in a `HAVING` clause**

The following example uses the `CASE` expression in a `HAVING` clause to restrict the rows returned by the `SELECT` statement. The statement returns the the maximum hourly rate for each job title in the HumanResources.Employee table. The `HAVING` clause restricts the titles to those that are held by men with a maximum pay rate greater than 40 dollars or women with a maximum pay rate greater than 42 dollars.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT JobTitle, MAX(ph1.Rate)AS MaximumRate
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS ph1 ON e.BusinessEntityID = ph1.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY JobTitle
HAVING (MAX(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' 
        THEN ph1.Rate 
        ELSE NULL END) > 40.00
     OR MAX(CASE WHEN Gender  = 'F' 
        THEN ph1.Rate  
        ELSE NULL END) > 42.00)
ORDER BY MaximumRate DESC;
```

For more details description of these example visit the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).

Also visit [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm) and [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php) for some examples with great details.

Answer (score 17):

you can also use:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN upper(t.name) like 'P%' THEN
          'productive'
         WHEN upper(t.name) like 'T%' THEN
          'test'
         WHEN upper(t.name) like 'D%' THEN
          'development'
         ELSE
          'unknown'
       END as type
FROM table t
```