# Insert records into a table with a condition in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have a table that has columns that I want to insert into another table with certain conditions. The closest I could get was using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304464/inserting-from-another-table-with-conditions-for-a-column).

This is how I want to do it:

```
if (cnt > 50, avg_account, else null) as avg_account
if (cnt > 50, avg_change, else null) as avg_change
```

As shown above, I want to insert some columns from `Table1` into `Table2` and especially `avg_account` and `avg_change` columns when `cnt` column in `Table1` is `> 50`.

I tried the following, I am not getting my desired output using the following code,

```
SELECT
    id, branch, account, total, change,
    'avg_account' = CASE
                       WHEN cnt > 50 THEN avg_account -- How can I refer to avg_account values?
                       ELSE 'Null'
                    END,
    'avg_change' = CASE
                      WHEN cnt > 50 THEN avg_change  -- How can I refer  to avg_change values?
                      ELSE 'Null'
                   END 
INTO
    Table2
FROM 
    Table1

PRINT '  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @@ROWCOUNT) + ' rows updated'
```

Is my approach correct? Can I get values as indicated in the code snippet? OR should I use a `where` clause or subquery?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select id, branch, account, total, change,
       (case when cnt > 50 then avg_account end) as avg_account,
       (case when cnt > 50 then avg_change end) as avg_change
into Table2
from Table1;
```

Notes:

- With no `else` clause, a `case` expression returns `NULL`.
- `NULL` and `'NULL'` are not the same thing.  The latter is a string.  The format is probably what you want.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases -- because the distinction between a column name and a string is not always obvious.
- Don't escape names that do not need to be escaped.
- If you want to *filter out* rows with a `cnt <= 50`, then use `where` rather than `case`.

Comment: @i.n.n.m . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

another approach is to put your condition into `where` and use two SQLs

```
 select * into table2 from table1 where cnt > 50

 insert into table2
 select id, branch, account, total, change, null, null from cnt <= 50
```

Your original query has several bugs

```
 select      id, branch, account, total, change,
        CASE WHEN cnt > 50 THEN avg_account 
        ELSE 'Null'
        END,
        CASE WHEN cnt > 50 THEN avg_change 
        ELSE 'Null'
        END 
into       Table2
from       Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a WHERE clause, like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
    (id, branch, account, total, change, avg_account, avg_change)
SELECT
    id, branch, account, total, change,
    avg_account, avg_change
FROM
    TABLE1
WHERE
    cnt > 50
```

I may also me misunderstanding you situation. Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: accepted answer is the one I was looking for. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct.  You actually have the logic correct.  Your syntax is your problem:

When you enter 'Null' into your database, it will enter the STRING VALUE 'Null', and NOT the NULL Value.  Take the quotes off your Nulls.

select      id, branch, account, total, change,
            'avg_account' = CASE
            WHEN cnt > 50 THEN avg_account 
            ELSE Null
            END,
            'avg_change' = CASE
            WHEN cnt > 50 THEN avg_change              ELSE Null
            END 
into       Table2

from       Table1
           print '  ' + convert(varchar,@@rowcount)+ ' rows updated'

Assuming avg_account and avg_change are columns in table 1.