# SELECT using 'CASE' in SQL

Tags: sql, select, case

I have a set of one to one mappings A -> apple, B-> Banana and like that..
My table has a column with values as A,B,C..

Now I'm trying to use a select statement which will give me the direct result

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN FRUIT = 'A' THEN FRUIT ='APPLE' 
     ELSE WHEN FRUIT ='B' THEN FRUIT ='BANANA'     
 FROM FRUIT_TABLE;
```

But I'm not getting the correct result, please help me..

Comment: aren't you missing an end and an alias at the end of the case

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement

Comment: This is basic SQL syntax that you could easily Google about a million examples of.  Also, you should probably be using a reference/translation table and a `JOIN` here instead of a `CASE` expression.

Comment: @DanBracuk AFAIK it doesn't.

Comment: i think you are missing 'end'. Please paste the result what you are getting

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is just the syntax of the case statement, it looks like this.

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN FRUIT = 'A' THEN 'APPLE' 
    WHEN FRUIT = 'B' THEN 'BANANA'     
  END AS FRUIT
FROM FRUIT_TABLE;
```

As a reminder remember; no assignment is performed the value becomes the column contents.  (If you wanted to assign that to a variable you would put it before the CASE statement).

Comment: This could also be written with `CASE FRUIT WHEN 'A'...`

Comment: I had to convert to Upper, because of the Case Sensitive and bingo.

Answer (score 5):

Change to:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN FRUIT = 'A' THEN 'APPLE' 
    WHEN FRUIT = 'B' THEN 'BANANA'     
  END
FROM FRUIT_TABLE;
```

Comment: this won't have a column name.

Comment: Not a requirement

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN FRUIT = 'A' THEN 'APPLE'
     WHEN FRUIT = 'B' THEN 'BANANA'
     ELSE 'UNKNOWN FRUIT'
  END AS FRUIT
FROM FRUIT_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

which platform ?

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN FRUIT = 'A' THEN 'APPLE' 
    ELSE FRUIT ='B' THEN 'BANANA' 
   END AS FRUIT     
FROM FRUIT_TABLE;
```