# Is SQL query having "case" with muliple condition in When valid?

Tags: sql

SQL query:

```
"SELECT Store_Name, CASE Store_Name WHEN 'abc','xyz' THEN Sales * 2  ELSE Sales END FROM Store_Information";
```

Are two values in "WHEN" clause allowed like in above query - **`WHEN 'abc','xyz' THEN Sales * 2`**?

**EDIT:** I don't need to run this query. I need to parse this query. I am getting this from `Tableau`.

**I want to know is this Query syntactically correct?**

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT using 'CASE' in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313025/select-using-case-in-sql)

Comment: Running the query would have given you the answer much faster than the time it took to ask the question.  But I'll answer your question anyway.  It's not syntactically valid.

Comment: The simple answer is, "no".

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks for replying.Tableau is internally sending this type of query to my driver. SQL Parser is not able to understand it. I did not find much on google. So, I asked here

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

**1) Simple case expression**

```
CASE Store_Name
   WHEN 'abc' THEN Sales * 2
   WHEN 'xyz' THEN Sales * 2
   ELSE Sales
END
```

**2) Searched case expression**. I think it would be better choice for your task

```
CASE WHEN Store_Name IN('abc', 'xyz')
     THEN Sales * 2
     ELSE Sales
END
```

Comment: I am not asking an alternate way to achieve this. Just want to know is this syntactically correct?

Comment: @Tom Tableau is internally sending this type of query to my driver. SQL Parser is not able to understand it. I did not find much on google. So, I asked here.