# SQL Case Statement refering other column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table like Which has column A & B

```
      A            B
      1            9
      1            8
      2            7
      2            5
```

I want to write query.

```
  Select case when B = 9 then A = 'X', when A = 2 then 'Y' end as A
```

Is it possible in SQL. Please guide me

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement

Comment: Is it possible? I am getting syntax error

Comment: Don't do A = 'X', instead write 'X'. The query will be `Select case when B = 9 then 'X' when A = 2 then 'Y' End as A`

Comment: Super Boss... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN B = 9 THEN 'X'
         WHEN A = 2 THEN 'Y'
    END ,
    A ,
    B
FROM    dbo.tblTest;
```