# Trying to avoid an Update Query

Tags: sql

I'd like to select a value from COL_B as COL_A based on conditions in COL C,D & E.
I am trying to avoid using an update query. Similar to a nested IF in Excel.

```
IF COL_C=TRUE AND COL_D=TRUE AND COL_E=TRUE
THEN SELECT COL_B AS COL_A
ELSE COL_A
```

I could just shove it into a temp table and update COL_A to COL_B based on the conditions, but I'd like to do it on the SELECT statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may be what you need:

```
SELECT my_result =
  CASE
    WHEN COL_C=TRUE AND COL_D=TRUE and COL_E=TRUE THEN COL_B
    ELSE COL_A
  END
 AS COL_A
 FROM my_table
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That worked.

[Result]=
        CASE 
            WHEN
                COL_A=TRUE 
            AND COL_B=TRUE 
            AND COL_C=TRUE
            THEN COL_D
        ELSE COL_E
        END