# Need to resolve the query

Tags: sql

The management of EasyShop would like to classify the items as cheap, affordable, expensive and very expensive. The classification is done if item unit price is between 0 and 499 then 'Cheap', if between 500 and 1999 then 'Affordable', if between 2000 and 4999 then 'Expensive' and if price is more than or equal to 5000 then 'Very Expensive'. Write a query to display the itemtype and classification of items. Display unique rows sorted by itemtype and classification in ascending order.

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemType,
CASE
Price BETWEEN 0 AND 499 THEN 'Cheap'
Price BETWEEN 500 AND 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
Price BETWEEN 2000 AND 4999 THEN 'Expensive'
Price >=5000 THEN 'Very Expensive'
END Classification
FROM Item
```

Comment: I think you need to add an `ORDER BY` and probably remove the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Query is not giving ouput.Showing Error that Misplaced FROM

Comment: Yes order by is needed.I will add it later.First i need to remove the misplaced FROM.

Comment: Please have a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something like the below? Check it out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
WHEN Price BETWEEN 0 AND 240 THEN 'Cheap'
WHEN Price BETWEEN 241 AND 1200 THEN 'Expensive' END AS Range 
FROM Products 
ORDER BY Price
```

Comment: Could you write what is the error or any idea?? What is not working??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *ORDER BY ItemType, Classification* to your query. You should also include *WHEN* in your *CASE* statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemType,
 CASE WHEN
      Price BETWEEN 0 AND 499 THEN 'Cheap'
      Price BETWEEN 500 AND 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
      Price BETWEEN 2000 AND 4999 THEN 'Expensive'
      Price >=5000 THEN 'Very Expensive'
 END Classification
 FROM Item
 ORDER BY ItemType, Classification
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the Query.
**CASE Syntax**

```sql
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

The following would be the correct query.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ItemType, CASE 
WHEN Price BETWEEN 0 AND 499 THEN 'Cheap'
WHEN Price BETWEEN 500 AND 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
WHEN Price BETWEEN 2000 AND 4999 THEN 'Expensive'
WHEN Price >=5000 THEN 'Very Expensive' END Classification
FROM Item
ORDER BY ItemType, Classification;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would be the correct query in ORACLE(mysql etc..).

```sql
SELECT distinct ItemType,
CASE  
    WHEN price between 0 and 499 THEN 'Cheap'
    WHEN price between 500 and 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
    WHEN price between 2000 and 4999 THEN 'Expensive'
    WHEN price >=5000 THEN 'Very Expensive'
END AS classification 
FROM Item order by ItemType,classification asc
```

Answer (score 0):

CHECK IT

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemType,CASE
WHEN Price BETWEEN 0 AND 499 THEN 'Cheap' 
WHEN Price BETWEEN 500 AND 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
WHEN Price BETWEEN 2000 AND 4999 THEN 'Expensive'
WHEN Price>=5000 THEN 'Very Expensive'
END Classification FROM ITEM WHERE (PRICE BETWEEN 0 AND 499) OR (PRICE BETWEEN 500 AND 
1999) OR (PRICE BETWEEN 2000 AND 4999) OR (PRICE>5000) GROUP BY ITEMTYPE,PRICE ORDER BY 
ITEMTYPE, CLASSIFICATION;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT distinct ItemType,
CASE 
WHEN
  Price BETWEEN 0 AND 499 THEN 'Cheap'
WHEN
  Price BETWEEN 500 AND 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
WHEN
  Price BETWEEN 2000 AND 4000 THEN 'Expensive'
else 'Very Expensive'
END Classification
FROM Item
ORDER BY ItemType, Classification
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate what this snippet does and how it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: This code snippet will going to classify the item as cheap,affordable,expensive and very expensive. create one more column named classification and displays unique rows sorted by itemtype and classification in ascending order.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT itemtype, 
CASE
      WHEN price BETWEEN 0 and 499 THEN 'Cheap'
      WHEN price BETWEEN 500 and 1999 THEN 'Affordable'
      WHEN price BETWEEN 2000 and 4999 THEN 'Expensive'
      WHEN price>=5000 THEN 'Very Expensive'
END  as classification 
  from item  order by itemtype, classification
```

1. He ask to display the unique value of item type and classification so I selected it with the help of Distinct.
2. Then given some conditions to create a classification column, so to create a classification column I used a CASE statement to satisfy all the conditions.
3. In the last he asked to display both the columns in ascending order so I used ORDER BY.

I hope it will help you.