# SQL "case when" query

Tags: oracle

[image]

I need this for my school project a query that i cannot create.

the table contains 4 columns:

`document id`, `party_id`, `full name`, `party role`.

And for a `doc_id` i have 2 rows, 1 for the `grantor` 1 for the `grantee`.
I want to make s single row but i did not succeed with case when.
Please help.

```
SELECT document_id, 
       case  when party_role ='grantor' then full_name 
       case  when party_role ='grantee' then full_name  
from sales.all_sales
```

Comment: I have some pointers for you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. So it's one table only with two records per document_id? Please show sample data and desired result.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-conditional.html#functions-case

Comment: Just follow the proper `case` syntax: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

Comment: below query returns 2 columns. i would like 3: docid, grantor, grantee

SELECT document_id,
       CASE(party_role)
           WHEN 'grantor'
           THEN full_name
           WHEN 'grantee'
           THEN full_name
           ELSE ''
       END
FROM sales.all_sales;

Comment: So there is always exactly two records per document_id; one for grantor, one for grantee? And we can safely ignore the party_id, i.e. it has no meaning here?

Comment: per document id there might be multiple names as grantors and multiple names as grantee case when i would like the names 1 after another

Comment: i would like the party role (it is either grantor either grantee) to become the name of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT document_id, 
   case  when party_role ='grantor' then full_name end Grantor,
   case  when party_role ='grantee' then full_name  end Grantee

from sales.all_sales
```

if you want to aggregate the field try :

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_ID,
LISTAGG(GRANTOR,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GRANTOR) GRANTOR,
LISTAGG(GRANTEE,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GRANTEE) GRANTEE
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT document_id, 
   case  when party_role ='grantor' then full_name end Grantor,
   case  when party_role ='grantee' then full_name  end Grantee

from sales.all_sales
)
GROUP BY DOCUMENT_ID
```

Comment: Hi Nucu,If the name of a Grantor or Grantee is repeated with a different party_id then Thorsten's aggregated field will display same name twice. My query has distinct for a reason.

Comment: Yes AK47. I have tested your theory and you are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT document_id,
       CASE(party_role)
           WHEN 'grantor'
           THEN full_name
           WHEN 'grantee'
           THEN full_name
           ELSE ''
       END
FROM sales.all_sales
```

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation. You want to have one result row per document_id, so group by it. You want to build a string of grantors and grantees each. Use `LISTAGG` for this.

```
select
  document_id, 
  listagg(case when party_role = 'grantor' then full_name end, ',')
          within group (order by full_name) as grantor,
  listagg(case when party_role = 'grantee' then full_name end, ',')
          within group (order by full_name) as grantee
from sales.all_sales
group by document_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g you can do it with `pivot` and `listagg` as aggregate function:

```
select * from t
 pivot (listagg(name, ', ') within group (order by name) 
        for role in ('grantor' grantors, 'grantee' grantees))
```

<sup>Demo:</sup>

```
with t(id, name, role) as (
    select 2, 'James',    'grantor' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Tom',      'grantor' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Victoria', 'grantee' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Anty',     'grantee' from dual )
select * from t
 pivot (listagg(name, ', ') within group (order by name) 
                            for role in ('grantor' grantors, 'grantee' grantees))
```

<sup>Result:</sup>

```
        ID  GRANTORS         GRANTEES
----------  ---------------  -----------------
         2  James, Tom       Anty, Victoria
```