# Conditionally use CASE...WHEN - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have two tables like so:

**tblOrders: OrderNo (pk), CurrentStepNo (fk)**

**tblSteps: StepNo (pk), OrderNo (fk), StepName, StepType, StepStart, StepStop**

`tblOrders` contains tons of information about our sales orders, while `tblSteps` contains tons of information regarding the proper sequential steps it takes to build the material we are selling.

I am trying to construct a query that follows this logic:

> "For all orders, select the current step name from the step table. If
>   the Step Type is equal to 'XO', then select the most recently
>   completed (where StepStop is not null) regular step (where StepStop is
>   equal to 'YY')"

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    tblOrders.*,
    tblSteps.StepName    
FROM
    tblOrders
        INNER JOIN tblSteps 
                ON tblOrders.OrderNo = tblSteps.OrderNo
               AND tblOrders.CurrentStepNo = tblSteps.StepNo
```

Which successfully returns to me the current step name for an in-process order. What I need to achieve is, when the `tblOrders.CurrentStepNo` is of type `'XO'`, to find the `MAX(tblSteps.StepStop) WHERE tblSteps.StepType = 'YY'`. However, I am having trouble putting that logic into my already working query.

***Note: I am sorry for the lack of sample data in this example. I would normally post but cannot in this instance. This is also not a homework question.***

I have reviewed these references:

[Case in Select Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/08/23/subqueries-in-case-expressions/

But no luck so far.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
    tblOrders.*,
    CASE
        WHEN tblSteps.StepType = 'XO' THEN (-- Some logic here)
        ELSE tblSteps.StepName
        END AS StepName    
 FROM
    tblOrders
        INNER JOIN tblSteps 
                ON tblOrders.OrderNo = tblSteps.OrderNo
               AND tblOrders.CurrentStepNo = tblSteps.StepNo
```

But am struggling to properly formulate the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join all steps, rank them with `ROW_NUMBER`, and stay with the best ranked:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    o.*,
    s.*,
    row_number() over 
      (partition by o.orderno
       order by case when s.steptype <> 'XO' and s.stepno = o.currentstepno then 1
                     when s.steptype <> 'YY' then 2
                     else 3 end, s.stepstop desc nulls last) as rn
  from tblorders o
  join tblsteps s on s.orderno = o.orderno
) ranked
where rn = 1
order by orderno;
```

Comment: I know I have not posted example data to test. How does this work when the `StepType` is not XO? I am confused as to how this solution accomplishes the requirements of above post, can you explain?

Comment: Look at the join. I join all its steps to an order. Then I number these steps per order (with `row_number() over (partition by o.orderno`). If there is a step with a steptype <> 'XO' matching the currentstepno it gets #1. Next come steptype 'YY' rows. I number these sorted by stepstop descending. So the highest one gets the next number (which is #1 or #2). At last I keep only #1s.