# Fix 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'' error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to implement this two when condition in the case expression but it is just not happening. Please help me fix this?

```
SELECT 
    BR, CID, TRNDATE, 
    CASE
        WHEN TRNTYPE = '108' THEN -1 ELSE 1 * TrnAmt/100
        WHEN TRNTYPE = '114' THEN (TrnIntAmt - TrnTaxAmt)/100
    END as TransactionAmount
FROM 
    T_TRNHIST
```

Comment: When in doubt how a something works, the documentation is a great place to start: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case in Select Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189216/case-in-select-statement)

Answer (score 4):

Query Must be like that

```
SELECT BR, CID, TRNDATE, 
CASE
    WHEN TRNTYPE = '108' THEN -1 
    WHEN TRNTYPE = '114' THEN (TrnIntAmt - TrnTaxAmt)/100
    ELSE 1 * TrnAmt/100
    END as TransactionAmount
FROM T_TRNHIST
```

Else condition would come at last once all when done

Answer (score 2):

just a little change, move the ELSE to before the END

```
SELECT BR, CID, TRNDATE, 
CASE
    WHEN TRNTYPE = '108' THEN -1 
    WHEN TRNTYPE = '114' THEN (TrnIntAmt - TrnTaxAmt)/100
    else 1 * TrnAmt/100
END as TransactionAmount
FROM T_TRNHIST
```