# Can you have if-then-else logic in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do select data from a table based on some kind of priority like so:

```
select product, price from table1 where project = 1

-- pseudo: if no price found, do this:
select product, price from table1 where customer = 2

-- pseudo: if still no price found, do this:
select product, price from table1 where company = 3
```

That is, if I found 3 products with prices based on `project = X`, I don't want to select on `customer = Y`. I just want to return the resulting 3 rows and be done.

How are you supposed to do stuff like this in SQL? Use some kind of CASE-statement for the pseudo-if's? Do a union or some other smart thing?

Edit: I'm using MS SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL...? For each one of them the control flow instructions set are bit different

Comment: You answered your own question! Use case statements!

Comment: look at CASE statement from SQL

Comment: Sorry, it is bit unclear. What do you mean no price found? Is that for no records found? and how many records do you need at final results? One or many?

Comment: Also see question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select

Comment: the flagged duplicate doesn't actually apply.   It was a question about in-query `IF` handling, and this is a question about control of flow handling

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can make the following sql query

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE project = 1) > 0) 
    SELECT product, price FROM table1 WHERE project = 1
ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE project = 2) > 0) 
    SELECT product, price FROM table1 WHERE project = 2
ELSE IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE project = 3) > 0)
    SELECT product, price FROM table1 WHERE project = 3
```

Comment: How do you this in a codeigniter query builder?

Comment: ORA-00900: sentencia SQL no válida

Comment: @delive This is MS SQL, not Oracle.

Comment: That's not valid... So not sure how it was upvoted 100 times.

Comment: @Dalibor What is your concern about the answer? It does not work for your?

Comment: MS SQL does not have an ELSE IF, so definitely does not work. I'd update the answer to say it's for Oracle which i think it is for.

Comment: @Dalibor Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Dalibor According to the link Transact SQL supports IF ELSE <statement> where <statement> can be another IF ELSE for simple cases or BEGIN END statement for more complicated scenarios or any other statement supported by SQL Server. Not sure which version you was using to run the query and why if failed but I remember that the syntax worked for me. You can find other examples in SO as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614843/t-sql-how-to-end-an-if-else-if-else-block)

Comment: Hi Alex, I wasn't talking about IF ELSE. I am talking about ELSE IF. It's a very big difference between the two.

Comment: Please check below links to know more regarding Common Alternatives to IF ELSE Logic in SQL Server with Simple Example

https://arulmouzhi.wordpress.com/2019/11/15/common-alternatives-to-if-else-logic-in-sql-server-with-simple-example/

https://arulmouzhi.wordpress.com/2020/01/08/common-alternatives-to-if-else-logic-in-sql-server-with-simple-example-in-sql-server-part-2/

Answer (score 31):

The CASE statement is the closest to an IF statement in SQL, and is supported on all versions of SQL Server:

```
SELECT CASE <variable> 
           WHEN <value>      THEN <returnvalue> 
           WHEN <othervalue> THEN <returnthis> 
           ELSE <returndefaultcase> 
       END 
  FROM <table>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: While CASE is useful on all version of MS SQL, more recent versions do have an IF ELSE functionality.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using `EXISTS` and `COUNT` just use `@@ROWCOUNT`:

```
select product, price from table1 where project = 1

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    select product, price from table1 where customer = 2

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    select product, price from table1 where company = 3
END
```

Comment: +1 for a good solution

Comment: this is not good solution...  does not use inherent db set capabilities.  i don't think it's correct either where there are multiple different products.  actually - i think most knowledgeable in dbs would consider this a poor solution.  this is exactly the type of thing that we try to teach people NOT to do.

Comment: beeing a programmer and not very into dbs, I think this solution looks the most simple to read and understand :) However, I get multiple result sets since it does more than 1 select. Is there any way to only return 1 resut set? Also, does anyone back up @mson on this being a bad idea?

Comment: new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132192/can-i-have-multiple-select-but-only-return-one-result-set

Comment: this type of syntax is intuitive and is fine for a quick and dirty solution.  in dbs it is not optimal because this syntax is procedural - it would be orders of magnitude slower than a proper set based query.

Comment: This will give a 1-3 result sets. This will be a horror to actually program against. Only useful for as a debugger query or something.

Answer (score 2):

With SQL server you can just use a CTE instead of IF/THEN logic to make it easy to map from your existing queries and change the number of involved queries;

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT product,price,1 a FROM table1 WHERE project=1   UNION ALL
    SELECT product,price,2 a FROM table1 WHERE customer=2  UNION ALL
    SELECT product,price,3 a FROM table1 WHERE company=3
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES product,price FROM cte ORDER BY a;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/175c0/5).

Alternately, you can combine it all into one `SELECT` to simplify it for the optimizer;

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES product,price FROM table1 
WHERE project=1 OR customer=2 OR company=3
ORDER BY CASE WHEN project=1  THEN 1 
              WHEN customer=2 THEN 2
              WHEN company=3  THEN 3 END;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fc00/1).

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether this helps:

```
select TOP 1
    product, 
    price 
from 
    table1 
where 
    (project=1 OR Customer=2 OR company=3) AND
    price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY company
```

Comment: This will return a result matching _any_ of the conditions without any priority order.

Answer (score 0):

there is a case statement, but i think the below is more accurate/efficient/easier to read for what you want.

```
select 
  product
  ,coalesce(t4.price,t2.price, t3.price) as price
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 on t1.product = t2.product and t2.customer =2
left join table1 t3 on t1.product = t3.product and t3.company =3
left join table1 t4 on t1.product = t4.product and t4.project =1
```

Comment: If you don't get a hit in `t1`, this will not return any results.

Comment: lol - t1, t2, t3 point to same table (as in poster's requirement) - but i see your point.  same solution though

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b847b/3, good for testing.

Answer (score 0):

--Similar answer as above for the most part. Code included to test

```
DROP TABLE table1
GO
CREATE TABLE table1 (project int, customer int, company int, product int, price money)
GO
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,0,50, 100, 40),(1,0,20, 200, 55),(1,10,30,300, 75),(2,10,30,300, 75)
GO
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES product
        , price
        , CASE WhereFound WHEN 1 THEN 'Project'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Customer'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Company'
            ELSE 'No Match'
            END AS Source
FROM 
    (
     SELECT product, price, 1 as WhereFound FROM table1 where project = 11
     UNION ALL
     SELECT product, price, 2 FROM table1 where customer = 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT product, price, 3 FROM table1 where company = 30
    ) AS tbl
ORDER BY WhereFound ASC
```