# Can i have multiple select but only return one result set

Tags: sql

If I have multiple selects like so:

```
select * from A where A.name = 'linköping'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
begin
    select * from A where A.amount = 45
end
```

...I get 1 result set if the first select returns stuff. But if it runs the second, I get two result sets; the first with no rows and the second with some rows.

Is there a way to only return the second result set if the second select is run ?

I write code like this because of Andrey Gordeev's answer to this post: [Can you have if-then-else logic in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085990/can-you-have-if-then-else-logic-in-sql)

(MSSQL 2000)

Thanks!

Comment: In this case you should use `IF EXISTS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to prevent the first select by checking if you will get any results back *before* running the select.

For example:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.name = 'linköping')
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.name = 'linköping'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.amount = 45
END
```

Comment: It would be great if you replace first line with `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE A.name = 'linkoping')`

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer Agreed. This will be a slight performance boost. I must confess that I copied-and-pasted the query from the line below :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work with IF-ELSE Logic. [Tested]

```
DECLARE @count as int
set @count = (SELECT count(1) from A where A.name = 'linköping')
if (@count = 0)
BEGIN
    select * from A where A.amount = 45
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select * from A where A.name = 'linköping'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible The returning results are depending on number of select statements.
If you want to do the single select follow @RB or @Jwalin Shah solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    select * from A where A.amount = 45
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select * from A where A.name = 'linköping'
END
```