# if query is not update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know best way to make my query's into a if statement. because I would like to use one function for my codeigniter edit main function,

So it combines both query's and makes it if query is not a update then is a insert way is best way

```
public function addUserGroup($data) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET 
    name = " . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
    permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . " ");
}

public function editUserGroup($user_group_id, $data) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET 
    name = " . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
    permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . " WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "'");
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: you can adapt what is used here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085990/can-you-have-if-then-else-logic-in-sql. Update the record, add `IF @@rowcount = 0 INSERT ......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set if/else condition using "user_group_id". I think this must be coming from post array like `$this->input->post('user_group_id')`.

So you can create one function which will check these conditions like below:

```
function my_function(){
   if($this->input->post('user_group_id')){
    // call update query
   }else{
    // call insert query
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to save values in variable  and pass var to query and try to add proper quoting to query vars

```
public function addUserGroup($data) {
  $perm = (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '');
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . "', permission = '" .$perm. "' ");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with one query pretty neat:

```
"INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET name = " . 
$this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . 
" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ". 
$this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET name = " . 
$this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . " 
WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "'");
```

The only thing required is a primary key on the table