# T-SQL How to end an IF-ELSE IF-ELSE block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I run the below procedure with the correct parameters so that the -1 value isn't returned, none of my DML statements are firing. I'm guessing that it's treating all my DML statements as part of the `ELSE` block.

*SQL Server 2014*

How do I end an IF-ELSE-ELSE-IF block?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [GenerateNumber] (
    @Code VARCHAR(2)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stringConcat VARCHAR = 'X';

    IF @Code = 'KP'
        SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
    ELSE IF @Code = 'RL'
        SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
    ElSE
        -- Return error code and stop processing
        SELECT -1;
        RETURN;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- Various DML statements...

        SELECT @successValue;
        RETURN;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT -1;
        RETURN;
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Okay you have to use `Begin` and `End` in the `Else` statement as it contains multiple lines of code.

```
    IF @Code = 'KP'
        SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
    ELSE IF @Code = 'RL'
        SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
    ElSE
    Begin
        -- Return error code and stop processing
        SELECT -1;
        RETURN;
    End
```

Answer (score 9):

Your indenting is lying to you.

```
IF @Code = 'KP'
     SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
 ELSE IF @Code = 'RL'
     SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
 ElSE
     -- Return error code and stop processing
     SELECT -1;  -- THIS is evaluated as the ELSE
     RETURN;     -- THIS is run regardless.
```

Only the 1st line after that last ELSE will be executed as an ELSE condidion. That RETURN will be run regardless. Your BEGIN TRY can't be reached.

Try this:

```
IF @Code = 'KP'
     SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
 ELSE IF @Code = 'RL'
     SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
 ElSE
     BEGIN
     -- Return error code and stop processing
     SELECT -1;
     RETURN;
     END
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want both `SELECT -1` and `RETURN` to be inside the `ELSE` you'll have to use a `BEGIN` / `END` block. Now only the `SELECT -1` is inside the else branch.

So you need

```
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT -1;
    RETURN;
  END
```

Answer (score 4):

The last `ELSE` in your If, ELSE IF, ELSE contains multiple lines of code. You need to start it with `BEGIN` and end it with `END`. See this [MSDN documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587(v=sql.110).aspx) for more details.

```
IF @Code = 'KP'
    SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
ELSE IF @Code = 'RL'
    SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
ElSE
    BEGIN
        -- Return error code and stop processing
        SELECT -1;
        RETURN;
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, RETURN always runs.

From a coding practice standard, you should always use BEGIN and END in SQL in my opinion to clearly state what is intended to be in the logical block. I prefer the same pattern in C# where I use braces even when not needed. The indentation is important in my opinion as well as it easily lets you track where it starts and finishes.

```
IF(1=2)
   BEGIN
      SELECT 1
   END
SELECT 2

IF(1=2) SELECT 1
   SELECT 2
```

These are equivalent in behavior, but the first clearly shows SELECT 1 is dependent on the logical condition above it.

What you really want is:

```
IF @Code = 'KP'
    BEGIN
        SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
    END
ELSE IF @Code = 'RL'
    BEGIN
        SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
    END
ElSE
    BEGIN
        -- Return error code and stop processing
        SELECT -1;
        RETURN;
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case (pun intended), you might be better off using a `CASE WHEN` construction, seeing you want to evaluate different values for your `@Code` variable. MSDN states that `CASE` is intended exactly for such scenarios:

```
Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.
```

I find it makes code a bit more readable for simple evaluations (but that could very well be a personal preference).

Your code would end up looking similar to this (pseudo-code. not tested):

```
CASE @Code 
    WHEN 'KP' THEN SET @stringConcat += 'Y';
    WHEN 'RL' THEN SET @stringConcat += 'Z';
    ElSE
        -- Return error code and stop processing
        SELECT -1;
        RETURN;
END
```

More on the `CASE` statement here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Your pseudo-code won't work.  `CASE` returns a _result expression_ (something leading to a value).  It doesn't perform flow control for other statements.