# How to use IF ELSE condition for SQL in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I want execute certain set of SQL statements based on parameters passed on from json and they all should be in single SQL.

I have 3 conditions namely

**1. Give
2. Take
3. Both**

Now in Netezza SQL,

I would like to have something as below:

```
if %input = 'Give'
   set of give sql statements
else if %input = 'Take'
    set of take sql statements
else
    set of both sql statements.
```

After searching I found below links,but not sure if this is possible in Netezza.

[Can you have if-then-else logic in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085990/can-you-have-if-then-else-logic-in-sql)

[How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Can anyone please guide me?

I am new to Netezza db

Thanks
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do this using `case` and [dynamic SQL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_executing_dynamic_queries.html) (you might need to check the syntax, since I haven't used Netezza much):

```
declare sql nvarchar(10000)
sql := case 
        when %input = 'Give' then 'statement1; statement2;'
        when %input = 'Take' then 'statement3; statement4;'
        else 'statement5; statement6;'
       end
execute immediate sql
```

Comment: Will check.Could you please explain the declaration of sql as nvarchar there?

Comment: @maddykemen That's just to declare a variable to hold the dynamic SQL statements to be executed, which will be returned by the `case` statement. But please correct me if the syntax to declare a variable is different in Netezza.

Comment: will try and let you know