# if then statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why the if then statement is not working here

```
declare @num integer(2);
set @num = 10;

begin
    if (@num < 10)
    Then
        print('hello');

    set @num = @num +1 ;

    else
        print('over');

    set @num = @num +1 ;
    END IF;
END;
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Then'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

Comment: remove then from your query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085990/can-you-have-if-then-else-logic-in-sql/15086050#15086050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you have if-then-else logic in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085990/can-you-have-if-then-else-logic-in-sql)

Comment: If you have **more than one statement** after your `IF` or `ELSE`, you must wrap it in  `BEGIN .... END` delimiters! And there's no `THEN` in T-SQL ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
 declare @num int;
 set @num = 10;

 if (@num < 10)
 begin
   print('hello');
   set @num = @num +1;
 end
 else 
    begin
      print('over');
      set @num = @num +1;
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 declare @num integer
 set @num = 10

 if (@num < 10)
 begin
   print('hello')
   set @num = @num +1
 end
 else begin
   print('over')
   set @num = @num +1
 end
```