# using if statement how to replace values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, sql-update, case

I have two tables,

**Database 1:**

**Table 1:**

- Id -001(int)
- Name -xxx(varchar)
- Male -0 (bit)
- Female-1 (bit)

**Database 2:**

**Table 2:**

- Id -1 (int)
- Ca.Name-yyy (varchar)
- Gender - M or F (varchar)

These are my tables. I want to update data from database2, Table 2 to database1, table1. So i create update query. But I have problem with Gender field

```
Select 'UPDATE T1
 SET T1.MALE ='+ CASE WHEN r.Gender = 'M' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

 FROM T2 As r
```

In the below code, what I starred I have a doubt how to use if statement here. Any one understand rectify my problem?

Answer (score 6):

Use `case when` for this purpose.

Follow this question :

[SQL Server: CASE WHEN OR THEN ELSE END => the OR is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported)

```
CASE  
  WHEN GENDER='M' THEN 0 
  ELSE 1 
END
```

This can be in your case.

For more syntax details: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, you need to use `CASE WHEN`. The query would look like:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET T1.MALE = CASE WHEN T2.caname = 'm' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    T1.female = CASE WHEN T2.caname = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  // you also need update this otherwise a person would end up with two genders :)
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO:](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fb58/4)

Comment: I have error like "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE Jobs 
SET T1.MALE =' to data type int."

Comment: in your question can you also post the `DATATYPE` of columns...like if its int, varchar, bit, etc...or post the entire error

Comment: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE Jobs SET T1.MALE =' to data type int."

Comment: i hope u r not using the select statement with the update statement...like in the question you have shown..it not the correct way...do it the way i have shown in the fiddle demo..first update then use select.