# SQL Views - Modify Returned Result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm a little stuck here.  I'm trying to modify a returned View based on a condition.  I'm fairly green on SQL and am having a bit of difficultly with the returned result.  Heres a partial component of the view I wrote:

```
WITH A AS (

SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fkidContract,fkidTemplateItem ORDER BY bStdActive DESC, dtdateplanned ASC) AS RANK,
  tblWorkItems.fkidContract AS ContractNo,
  ....
FROM tblWorkItems
WHERE   fkidTemplateItem IN
                    (2895,2905,2915,2907,2908,
                     2909,3047,2930,2923,2969,
                     2968,2919,2935,2936,2927,
                     2970,2979)
AND ...
)
SELECT * FROM A WHERE RANK = 1
```

The return result is similar to the following:

```
ContractNo| ItemNumber |    Planned   |  Complete
  001     |    100     |  01/01/1900  | 02/01/1900
  001     |    101     |  03/04/1900  | 02/01/1901
  001     |    102     |  03/06/1901  | 02/08/1900
  002     |    100     |  01/03/1911  | 02/08/1913
```

This gives me the results I expect, but due a nightmare crystal report I need to alter this view slightly.  I want to take this returned result set and modify an existing column with a value pulled from the same table and the same Contract relationship, something like the following:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Completed = ( SELECT  R.Completed
                        FROM myTable R
                            INNER JOIN A
                                ON A.ContractNo = R.ContractNo
WHERE A.ItemNumber = 100 AND R.ItemNumber = 101
                        )
```

What I'm trying to do is modify the "Completed Date" of one task and make it the complete date of another task if they both share the same ContractNo field value.

Comment: If you are using the keyword "with", you are not green on sql.  The key to your problem is the sql keyword "case".  You use it to modify your query, not change the results afterwards.

Comment: You're only pulling in 2 columns with your CTE expression, but the result you posted shows 4 columns.  Was there some code that was cut off in your example?

Comment: Lloyd, there was lots.  I posted the parts I considered relevant.  I can post the entire view if you'd like.
@DanBracuk - The case keyword was an incorrect copy + paste + modify.  I've removed it and updated.

Comment: Is myTable same table as "A" or are they two different tables?

Comment: You should not really be changing your data to satisfy a reporting requirement!  If the data is there then you should alter your query.

Comment: Anup - Same Table.
@LoztInSpace - I'm changing the view, which was built purely for this report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that actually reading the [vendor documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) helps :)

```
SELECT 
  column1,
  column2 = 
    case
      when date > 1999 then 'some value'
      when date < 1999 then 'other value'
      else 'back to the future'
    end

FROM ....
```

For reference, the total query did a triple inner join over ~5 million records and this case statement was surprisingly performant.

I suggest that this gets closed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the ItemNumber relationships between A and R (perhaps it was just for testing...), but it seems like you don't really want to UPDATE anything, but you want to use a different value under some circumstances.  So, maybe you just want to change the non-cte part of your query to something like:

```
SELECT A.ContractNo, A.ItemNumber, A.Planned, 
       COALESCE(R.Completed,A.Completed) as Completed
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable R
ON A.ContractNo = R.ContractNo
AND A.ItemNumber = 100 AND R.ItemNumber = 101  -- I'm not sure about this part
WHERE A.Rank = 1
```