# Using Case in SQL

Tags: php, sql, case

My sql table is like

```
posts-> id  postedby   timestamp
        1     1        12716826

comments-> id     postid     comby     tstamp      condition
            1       1           1         12716826      me
            2       1           1         12716826      all
            1       1           2         12716826      me
            1       1           3         12716826      all
```

My question is when i make a query to fetch all comments of post 1 . i want following condition

> The comment with condition me should be visible to only me or post owner

I made a query like
    $myid=2;
    $postbyid=1;

```
$res=$db->query("SELECT * from comments where postid='$postbyid' 
                order by tstamp desc");
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
{
if($row['comby']==$uid || $row['comby']=='$postbyid')
{
$data[]=$row;
}

else
{

if($row['condition']!='me')
{
$data[]=$row;
}
}
}
```

This may be wrong.
Is there a way do this using `SQL CASE`?

like

```
 SELECT * from comments where postid='$postbyid' CASE WHEN comby='$myid' 
THEN SHOW ALL WHEN combyid='$postbyid' THEN SHOW ALL else dont 
show this row order by tstamp desc
```

Comment: Yes that's perfectly possible. Check this out for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to tweak your query conditions:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM comments
   WHERE postid = '$postbyid'
     AND comby IN ('$myid', '$postbyid')
ORDER BY tstamp DESC
```

I didn't get what you want with `condition` field, but from that query you can add another `AND` condition to satisfy the visibility restriction.

Note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, seems like that you're using *mysqli* module to work with database, so take a look at prepared statements section of *mysqli* manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Good luck!