# sql IF in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that pulls data from 2 different on 2 different servers as follows:

```
SELECT 
        LocalDB.Record_ID,  
        LocalDB.Total/1440 as TotalTime,
        ((REMOTE_ACTIVE.Time_Adjusted) - (REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.CALCTimeSec)) as TimeLeft,
        LocalDB.isManualEntry
        FROM LocalDatabase.dbo.Records LocalDB left join
                   [RemoteServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[ActiveWO] REMOTE_ACTIVE ON
                   LocalDB.WO_ID = REMOTE_ACTIVE.[PO_ID]
                   left join [RemoteServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[ActiveWOTimes] REMOTE_ACTIVETimes ON
            LocalDB.WO_ID = REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.[PO_ID]
```

What can happen is that sometimes the "TimeLeft" value can be 0. When that happens I want to replace that value with something like

```
IF(TimeLeft is 0 or null)
(getdate() - LocalDB.CreatedDate) as TimeElapsed
```

The thing is, I'm not sure how to implement such an IF statement or if it is even possible.

Comment: you can use case statement in sql serve r. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported

Comment: Thanks but that does not show the full syntax, for example where does the CASE go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `case` statement:

```
SELECT LocalDB.Record_ID,  
       LocalDB.Total/1440 as TotalTime,
       (case when REMOTE_ACTIVE.Time_Adjusted - REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.CALCTimeSec <> 0
             then REMOTE_ACTIVE.Time_Adjusted - REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.CALCTimeSec
             else getdate() - LocalDB.CreatedDate
        end) as TimeLeft,
       LocalDB.isManualEntry
FROM LocalDatabase.dbo.Records LocalDB left join
     [RemoteServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[ActiveWO] REMOTE_ACTIVE
     ON LocalDB.WO_ID = REMOTE_ACTIVE.[PO_ID] left join
     [RemoteServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[ActiveWOTimes] REMOTE_ACTIVETimes
     ON LocalDB.WO_ID = REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.[PO_ID];
```

I assume in the question that `TimeElapsed` is the replacement for `TimeLeft`.

Comment: Thanks that did the job. The query seems to take a bit longer, would it be due to the query or because or latency?

Comment: @sd_dracula . . . I seriously doubt that adding this `case` statement would have much impact on performance.  I suspect that is just natural variation, based on what is running on the server and how what data is in the various page caches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Subquery

```
Select RecordID,TotalTime,TimeLeft,IsManualEntry,
       CASE WHEN TimeLeft=0 OR TimeLeft is null THEN DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), CreationDate)
            ELSE  CreationDate END AS TimeElapsed,

FROM (
        SELECT  LocalDB.CreatedDate As CreationDate
        LocalDB.Record_ID as RecordID,  
        LocalDB.Total/1440 as TotalTime,
        ((REMOTE_ACTIVE.Time_Adjusted) - (REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.CALCTimeSec)) as TimeLeft,
        LocalDB.isManualEntry as IsManualEntry
        FROM LocalDatabase.dbo.Records LocalDB left join
                   [RemoteServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[ActiveWO] REMOTE_ACTIVE ON
                   LocalDB.WO_ID = REMOTE_ACTIVE.[PO_ID]
                   left join [RemoteServer].[Reporting].[dbo].[ActiveWOTimes]  
                   REMOTE_ACTIVETimes ON
                   LocalDB.WO_ID = REMOTE_ACTIVETimes.[PO_ID]
      ) Z
```

More about [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)