# IF statement from a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table with some columns containing numbers.
I want to use the columns in the temp table and compare them WITH an IF statement.

```
...


INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC [p_GetComplete] @Car_ID

IF Col1 + Col2 = Col3
BEGIN
 PRINT 'OK'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
 PRINT 'NO'
END

...
```

Comment: In my humble opinion if you're doing IFs in the database you're doing something wrong... SQL is a set based language, your procedural logic should be in your application not your storage.

Comment: You must SELECT the values, is there always only one row, if not do you want to perform an action for each row matching the condition? If so what action?

Comment: @AlexK. yes there will always only be one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Is made to operate on SET, so avoid CASE WHEN and IF as long as you can:

You can  do it this way (recommended):

```
SELECT 'Ok' FROM #tmp WHERE Col1+Col2=Col3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NO' FROM #tmp WHERE NOT (Col1+Col2=Col3)
```

or this way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Col1+Col2=Col3 THEN 'Ok' ELSE NO FROM #tmp WHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement, when wanting to insert different value to #tmp table, according to some conditions.

Such as on:

[SQL Server: CASE WHEN OR THEN ELSE END => the OR is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported)

If you want searching every record, and do some printing, there is good example on:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the `exec` is only returning one row and the only way you can capture the data is into a table.  You can rewrite the stored procedure to have proper `OUTPUT` parameters, but let's assume that's not possible.

You can do what you want as:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC [p_GetComplete] @Car_ID

IF exists(select * from #temp where Col1 + Col2 = Col3)
BEGIN
 PRINT 'OK';
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
 PRINT 'NO';
END;
```

That is, if a row exists where the condition is true, then print `'OK'`.