# Select Query in Oracle giving issue

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:

```
select * from v_fi_trans_logs 
where case_num like '105'
AND TRANS_DT=CAST('09-JUL-2014' AS DATE);
```

Doesn't return me any records.

But If I do a select as

```
select TRANS_DT,CAST('09-JUL-2014' AS DATE) from v_fi_trans_logs where case_num like '105'
```

It returns me values which is equal.

```
    TRANS_DT   CAST('09-JUL-2014' AS DATE) 
----------------------------------------------    
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
    09-JUL-14   09-JUL-14
```

Can anyone help me out, with the issue here.

Any inputs will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by HIT and TRAIL method :

It worked with:

```
select * from v_fi_trans_logs 
where case_num like '105'
AND TRANS_DT LIKE CAST('09-JUL-2014' AS DATE);
```

That is,replacing **"="** with **"LIKE"** solves the issue.

Comment: If you are using `like` oeprator, make sure you have something like `like '105%'`. Of course when you are using like operator, it does a full table scan of all rows which result in more time for execution of sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using :

```
like '105' AND TRANS_DT=CAST('09-JUL-2014' AS DATE);
```

You can use like as a comparation of numbers and strings… only once.

But if you are trying to compare ´105´ AND TRANS_DT=CAST('09-JUL-2014' AS DATE) logically. You cannot do it. The translation will be ( 7 &  true ) for example.

Check out this solution the error is very similar.
[How can I use "OR" condition in MySQL CASE expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630603/how-can-i-use-or-condition-in-mysql-case-expression/24630776#24630776)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure TRANS_DT is truncated?
If it has a time component it will not work when compared to a date.

Try the following:

```
select * 
  from v_fi_trans_logs 
 where case_num like '105'
   and trunc(trans_dt) = date '2014-07-09';
```

Or if you have an index on trans_dt that you want to use:

```
where case_num like '105'
  and trans_dt >= date '2014-07-09'
  and trans_dt <  date '2014-07-10'
```