# Checking if any column has value = 1 in SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want a select statement which will find me if there is any row with column expired value = 1.

This is what I am trying with no luck,

```
Declare @FruitID INT;
SET @FruitID = '2876';

 SELECT 
    dbo.IsFruitExpired(@FruitID, Fruits.CrateID) AS FruitExpired
 FROM 
    Fruits  WHERE   Fruits.ID = @FruitID
```

**Result**

```
FruitExpired
0
0
1
0
```

So I want to return 1 if there is any row with value = 1 otherwise return 0, I am going to add this select statement in a function.

Comment: USE CASE STATEMENT
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply `MAX` function to result. If there are just 1 and 0 then it will work. Note that if you return `BIT` type from function you will need to cast:

```
Declare @FruitID INT;
SET @FruitID = '2876';
DECLARE @Result AS int

 SELECT @Result = MAX(dbo.IsFruitExpired(@FruitID, Fruits.CrateID)) AS FruitExpired FROM 
    Fruits  WHERE   Fruits.ID = @FruitID
```

If `BIT` is returned:

```
 SELECT @Result = MAX(CAST(dbo.IsFruitExpired(@FruitID, Fruits.CrateID) AS INT)) AS FruitExpired
 FROM  Fruits  WHERE   Fruits.ID = @FruitID
```

Or you can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE dbo.IsFruitExpired(@FruitID, CrateID) = 1)
   SET @Result = 1
ELSE
   SET @Result = 0
```

Comment: max(), the simplest solution :) great. @Giorgi

Comment: I didn't tested them yet, but i'll accept it as a answer, thanks

Comment: @chridam, I didn't declare that. OP has declared. May be he has ID column as char, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you want to check on the any column in the Fruits table, this can be possible with the use of dynamic sql and the [**case statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @FruitID NVARCHAR(5);
SET @FruitID = '2876';
SET @tb = N'dbo.[Fruits]';

SET @sql = N'SELECT 
                CASE';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = 1 THEN 1'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' ELSE 0
                   END AS FruitExpired
               FROM ' + @tb + '
               WHERE Fruits.ID = ' + @FruitID
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this for now,

```
    Declare @FruitID INT;
    SET @FruitID = '2876';
    DECLARE @Result AS int

    IF
      (SELECT  COUNT(*)
          FROM Fruits
          WHERE dbo.IsFruitExpired(@FruitID, Fruits.CrateID) = 1 )
    = 1

     SET @Result = 0
   ELSE
     SET @Result = 1

   RETURN (@Result)
```

Comment: This will return nothing if there are no rows with 1. Or it will return many rows if there are many rows with 1. Also edit your question rather then adding answer.

Comment: see my answer. There are 2 ways.