# SQL IF ELSE Calculated Column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to set a column value to "Vacant" or "Full" based on another column value. So an example would be: If Column X = 0 Then Column Y Value = "Full" Else Column Y Value = "Vacant".

Thanks!

Comment: please show us your sql

Comment: You need to use CASE statement in SQL,[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487892/sql-server-case-when-or-then-else-end-the-or-is-not-supported) so answer has an example.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Why store same value twice, once as 0 and once as FULL... May end up with data inconsistency. Create a view instead! (If you really need to do this, handle it with triggers, or as a "computed column".)

Comment: @DarshanMehta,  CASE expression, not case statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CASE`

```
UPDATE t SET ColumnY = (CASE WHEN ColumnX = 0 THEN 'Full' ELSE 'Vacant' END)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.