# SUM number but only if they are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is a SQL function exists to SUM some numbers in a column but only if they are different ?

Comment: No, but you can use the `case` command. Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5487936/1542307

Comment: Like `sum(distinct foo)`?

Comment: `in a row`? do you mean you want to add different columns? Can you show us some sample data and expected output?

Comment: You can improve this question by adding sample data, expected result and the query you have tried so far. Importantly tag the `RDBMS` you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME)) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Can I make : `SELECT *, SUM(DISTINCT COALESCE(STX_Amount, 0))) AS ApplicableTaxes FROM...`?

Comment: @user7347588 - Can you add sample data and expected result. Also the `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: The parentheses around the column_name are meaningless and are not related in any way to the DISTINCT keyword

Answer (score 4):

You can use subqueries to achive this:

```
Select Sum(TBL.column) From
( Select distinct column From Table) as TBL
```