# Select is not valid at this position expecting (

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have written a query with CASE but I am getting () problem.

```
select SM.subscriber_name as name ,
       SM.accountType as accountType,
       SM.middlename as middleName,
       SM.lastname as lastName,
       SM.title as title,
       SM.email as email,
       SM.company as company,
       SM.email1 as aEmail,
       ,
       SM.zipcode as zipcode,
       SM.phone_no as phoneNumber,
       SM.landlinenumber as landlineNumber,
       SM.login_id as loginId, 
       SD.subscriberType as subscriptionType,
       SD.product_id as productType,
       case SM.state when 'null' then '' as state else STDD.state_name as state end,
       case SM.city when 'null' then '' as city else  CDD.city_name as city end,
       case SM.country when 'null' then '' as country else CD.country_name as country end,
       SD.fulldownloadaccess as fullDownloadAccess,
       SD.emailid_limit as emailLimit,
       SD.acessTime as planTime
from subscriber_master SM , 
     subsciber_details SD,
     city_details CDD,
     state_details STDD, 
     country_details CD
where SM.subscriber_id=16704 and 
      SM.subscriber_id=SD.subscriber_id and 
      SM.country = CD.country_id and
      SM.state = STDD.state_id and
      SM.city = CDD.city_id;
```

Please help me where I can put the brackets

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: [CASE statement syntax in MS-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487936/7124761)

Comment: might be check for syntax --> `SM.email1 as aEmail` after this two `,,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you are interested to show the NULL's as empty values, so, you need to rebuild your query like:

```
  CASE sm.state 
          WHEN 'null' THEN ''  AS state 
          ELSE stdd.state_name AS state 
                                  end,
```

To be rewritten as:

```
  CASE  
          WHEN sm.state IS NULL THEN ''  
          ELSE stdd.state_name END AS state,
```

And the same for all 'NULL'. Also, the AS  should be written after the END of the CASE

REVIEWED: Just realised that the sentence below should return the same but is much more compact and easier to read:

```
ISNULL(sm.state, '') AS state,
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your query. Firstly your `CASE` expressions are written incorrectly, the expression must be complete before any `AS` part (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)) so for example,

```
case SM.state when 'null' then '' as state else STDD.state_name as state end,
```

should be written as

```
case SM.state when 'null' then '' else STDD.state_name end as state,
```

Additionally if you are checking for a `NULL` value, rather than a string value of `'null'`, you need to write the `CASE` expression as:

```
case when SM.state IS NULL then '' else STDD.state_name end as state
```

Also part way down you have an extra `,` (between `SM.email1 as aEmail,` and `SM.zipcode as zipcode,`).

However none of these problems will give you the message in your title, is there some code you haven't shown us?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `case` statement as shown below it will check both `null` and blank values

```
case ISNULL(SM.[state],'') when '' then '' else STDD.state_name end as [state],
       case ISNULL(SM.city,'') when '' then '' else CDD.city_name end as city,
       case ISNULL(SM.country,'') when '' then '' else CD.country_name end as country
```

You should use `join` for providing where conditions between different tables in select statement. Alternatively you can use the below modified query

```
select SM.subscriber_name as name ,
       SM.accountType as accountType,
       SM.middlename as middleName,
       SM.lastname as lastName,
       SM.title as title,
       SM.email as email,
       SM.company as company,
       SM.email1 as aEmail,       
       SM.zipcode as zipcode,
       SM.phone_no as phoneNumber,
       SM.landlinenumber as landlineNumber,
       SM.login_id as loginId, 
       SD.subscriberType as subscriptionType,
       SD.product_id as productType,
       case ISNULL(SM.[state],'') when '' then '' else STDD.state_name end as [state],
       case ISNULL(SM.city,'') when '' then '' else CDD.city_name end as city,
       case ISNULL(SM.country,'') when '' then '' else CD.country_name end as country,
       SD.fulldownloadaccess as fullDownloadAccess,
       SD.emailid_limit as emailLimit,
       SD.acessTime as planTime
from subscriber_master SM, 
     subsciber_details SD,
     city_details CDD,
     state_details STDD, 
     country_details CD      
where SM.subscriber_id=16704
 and  SM.subscriber_id=SD.subscriber_id and 
      SM.country = CD.country_id and
      SM.[state] = STDD.state_id and
      SM.city = CDD.city_id;
```